# How to scrape the youtube comments with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape youtube comments so that each row contains the title of the video, author of comment, and comment itself. As seen in the code below I open the drive successfully and get rid of some authentication and cookie messages as well. Scroll enough to get the first comments loaded. After this happens I still am not able to get the comment text by xpath as seen below.

```
csv_file = open('funda_youtube_comments.csv', 'w', encoding="UTF-8", newline="")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

writer.writerow(['title', 'comment', 'author'])

PATH = r"C:\Users\veiza\OneDrive\Desktop\AUAS\University\Quarter 2\Online Data Mining\Project1test\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWQaP9txG6M&t=76s")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,700);')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='dismiss-button']"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://consent.google.com']")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='introAgreeButton']"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
title = driver.title
print(title)
time.sleep(5)

totalcomments= len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="content-text"]"""))
if totalcomments < 50:
    index = totalcomments
else:
    index = 50

youtube_dict ={}

ccount = 0
while ccount < index:
    try:
        comment = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')[ccount].text
    except:
        comment = ""
    try:
        authors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@id="author-text"]/span')[ccount].text
    except:
        authors = ""
    try:
        title = title
    except:
        title = ""

    youtube_dict['comment'] = comment
    youtube_dict['author'] = authors
    youtube_dict['video title'] = title

    writer.writerow(youtube_dict.values())
    ccount = ccount + 1

print(youtube_dict)
driver.close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: >>I still am not able to get the comment text by xpath. What does it mean ? Do you get exception ? Do you get empty value ?

Comment: I get empty value @Disappointed

Comment: When something is hard to do using Selenium, that often means that it's illegal. You really want to use their API's , it's often faster to go that route than stick with using Selenium as a hammer.

Comment: @ConradB actually I managed to scrape the youtube comments. below you'll find my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to scrape youtube comments. below you can see the solution.

```
options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        PATH = r"C:\Users\veiza\OneDrive\Desktop\AUAS\University\Quarter 2\Online Data " \
               r"Mining\Project1test\chromedriver.exe "
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, options=options)
        driver.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(5)

        try:
            title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/h1/yt-formatted-string').text
            comment_section = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="comments"]')
        except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            error = "Error: Double check selector OR "
            error += "element may not yet be on the screen at the time of the find operation"
            print(error)

        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", comment_section)
        time.sleep(7)

        last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

        while True:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(2)
            new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
            if new_height == last_height:
                break
            last_height = new_height

        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")

        try:
            accounts_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="author-text"]')
            comment_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')
        except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            error = "Error: Double check selector OR "
            error += "element may not yet be on the screen at the time of the find operation"
            print(error)

        accounts = [elem.text for elem in accounts_elems]
        comments = [elem.text for elem in comment_elems]

        for comment_index in range(len(comment_elems)):
            yield {
                'title': title,
                'url': driver.current_url,
                'account': accounts[comment_index],
                'comment': comments[comment_index]
            }
```

Comment: For taking the time to paste a solution and to write such readable code, this answer should really get 10 points. Well organised example code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it simple, you can use tube_dl

```
pip install tube_dl
```

This module has Comments class that can help you with processing comments.
Here's the simple usage of that:

```
from tube_dl.comments import Comments
comments = Comments('yt url').process_comments()
```

#If you want limited comments, you can specify that. Ex : process_comments(count=45)

Feel free to raise issues at github.com/shekharchander/tube_dl. I'll be happy to resolve issues.